# cannot create a qwidget without qapplication although qapplication is included

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication

Following error has showed up all of a sudden:

> QWidget: Cannot create a QWidget without QApplication

It was working fine and I have `QApplication` included and a `QApplication` object declared before `MainWindow`, but the error is still there.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: what error?????

Comment: I recommend you read the following to improve your questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the error that is in the title ?

Comment: Try to have a short and descriptive title, and explain in detail in the question body. We give more importance to the content as it gives us more information about the error. Going to the point, that error is caused when you want to create a widget before creating QApplication.

Comment: And how would I solve it ?

Comment: I recommend going to the Build menu of QtCreator and running Clean All, and then run qmake.

Comment: Okay I'll try it, thank you ^^

Comment: Quite apart from the question I recommend you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so that you know the rules and good practices in SO.

Comment: Alright, thank you again, it finally worked ^^